# How to change the line COLOR when setting ShowLines = TRUE

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, treeview

How can I set the color of the line when setting ShowLines to TRUE? Either in C# or setting a Property, when using Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you even have __one__ look at the properties??

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the **LineColor** property of the TreeView control.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - But I do not have that option.

Comment: I tried to upload a screen capture (like you had done) showing the properties (and no "LineColor") - but I could not figure out how to upload that screen capture.

Comment: For screen shot , edit your question and click on image tag or Ctrl + G; it opens up a window where you can drag  the image or copy paste or upload a image

Comment: I found it - There is a link at the bottom of the TreeView property page "Customize Line Images" that opened additional properties, including LineColor.  I just had to auto create a Customize Line Images.  Thank you to all.  I am fixed up now

Answer (score 0):

There is a link at the bottom of the TreeView property page "Customize Line Images" that opened additional properties, including LineColor. I just had to auto create a Customize Line Images. Thank you to all. I am fixed up now.
[Here is a screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZwCD.png)